# Laravel response download not working inside Route middleware and prefix

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:0','auth']],function(){
    Route::prefix('s')->group(function () {
        Route::name('s.')->group(function () 
   {Route::get('order/po/download/{item}', function($item = ''){
    return response()->download(storage_path('app/public'.$item));
 });
```

The routing URL will be like:

```
s/order/po/download/$item
```

The issue is everytime I access this url it will bounce to login page for no reason.

Can any help with this? It works in my local vagrant. However, when I push the project onto a live server, it always redirect to login even I have already logged in.

If I put it outside which is accessible for everyone before the Middleware Route (not the best solution but it works):

```
Route::get('order/po/download/{item}', function($item = ''){
    return response()->download(storage_path('app/public'.$item));
 });
```

Added Role middleware :-

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next,$role)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
        // Check if user has the role This check will depend on how your roles are set up
        if($user->role_id == $role)
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->back();
        }


}
```

}

Comment: Are you using same .env file and set `chmod` folder permissions?

Comment: post your middleware and identify which of the two caused the login page redirect

Comment: Hi Paras, Updated the question with Role Middleware.

Comment: Seva, checked the permission is there access chmod -R 777 already. :(

Comment: You shouldn't ever land on the login page when you're authenticated because of the 'guest' middleware.  Sounds like you're issue is with your auth session, not the route.

Comment: Hi Devon, Noted I'll double check on the Auth where causes this issue.